# Auth::user not working in laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I'm creating a messaging application. User logs in and then his conversations are displayed to him.

i used `Auth::attempt` to check the user(after he submits the login form) . After successful login, he is redirected to a route(conversations) which uses respective controller method(HomeController@conversations).

In the method, i need to know the user's id so that i could fetch his conversation list. SO i need to use `Auth::user()->id`, wherever needed.

NOw when i'm using `Auth::user()->id`, it is showing an error(trying to get property from non-object).

i tried print_r(Auth::user) and the result was blank.

On localhost, everthing is working fine, but i'm facing this issue on the live server. `Auth::attempt` is working fine, but `Auth::check()` and `Auth::user()` are not.

Comment: Make sure that the app/storage directory is writable by the Web Server

Comment: i checked the directory using filezilla and there are several files in the sessions folder of app directory. So i guess it's writable.

Comment: Maybe you uploaded those files from your localhost. Delete them and see if the Web Server can create new ones.

Comment: i deleted all the files and even created a new session value manually before redirection(Session::put('test', 'dummyvalue')).

New files were created in the sessions directory. i tried print_r(Session::all()) to view the session. It showed a token session(which  i think created by the login form), but didn't show my manually created session. 

However, i opened the files in the session directory and my manually created session value was stored there.

Comment: Does the `Auth::user()` return `NULL` when you `dd(Auth::user())` in the attempt success body?

Comment: i used print_r(Auth::user()) in the attempt function and it showed the details of the user, so it's working before redirection.